# How to filter in Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

Sphinx data:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| id       | car_id      | filter_id   |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 37280991 |        4261 |          46 |
| 37280992 |        4261 |          18 |
| 37281000 |        4261 |           1 |
| 37281002 |        4261 |          28 |
| 51056314 |        4277 |          18 |
| 51056320 |        4277 |           1 |
| 51056322 |        4277 |          28 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have a page that show cars and you can apply filters. I'm trying that Sphinx return the cars that have filter 1 and 46. If you take a look the above table, you will see that just one car(4261) have both filters. The problem is that I don't know how to apply this in Sphinx.

```
$this->cs->SetFilter('filter_id', array(1, 46)); // this don't work because show me both(4261, 4277) cars, because work like a "in"
$this->cs->SetGroupBy('car_id', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->cs->SetFilter('filter_id', array(1)); 
$this->cs->SetFilter('filter_id', array(46));
```

Both filters apply, and **both** need to match. In effect they are 'AND'ed.

Comment: The filters will never match, because in every record has just one filter. So, if you apply the code like this:
$this->cs->SetFilter('filter_id', array(1)); 
$this->cs->SetFilter('filter_id', array(46)); 

this will try to find in the next record
37280991 |        4261 |          46 
46 and 1. Therefore, this is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, misread the question, missed the fact using group by. THought using a MVA.

... so have to be a bit more creative. Alas will probably need to use SphinxQL, rather than SphinxAPI. As sphinxQL has `HAVING`

```
SELECT id,car_id FROM index WHERE filter_id IN (1,46) GROUP BY car_id HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

This only includes rows where multiple documents match per car (ie matches each time using the IN clause. If there can be duplicates (like two rows with filter_id=1 then can perhaps use `COUNT(DISTINCT filter_id)` instead? )

Comment: Thanks ! this is useful for me